# Eclipse throwing Gradle errors when importing project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to produce a Minecraft mod for 1.12.2, but eclipse is throwing errors whenever I try to import the root folder of the 1.12.2 mdk. Here is the error

https://pastebin.com/twTSdmPu

```
I couldnt post pastebin link without code so here you go
```

Comment: What's your `java -version`?

Comment: @Lucan it is 13.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your Java version is too high, downgrade to [Java version 8](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot) (1.8) and configure your IDE to use Java 8 ([IntelliJ](https://www.baeldung.com/intellij-change-java-version) / [Eclipse](https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-change-java-version)).